Clerk Bug: UserResource type from useUser() and @clerk/types do not match
I tried to pass the user coming from useUser() but I get the following error:
Type 'UserResource' is missing the following properties from type 'UserResource': passkeys, createPasskey
Upon further investigation I stumbled upon the problem that UserResource type used in useUser() does not include passkeys and createPasskey that is coming from UserResource at @clerk/types
Parent Component:
import { useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default function Page(props: Props) {
  const { isLoaded, user } = useUser();

  return (
    <>
      ...
          <Form user={user} />
    </>
  );

ChildComponent:
import { UserResource } from "@clerk/types";

type Props = {
  user: UserResource;
};

const Form = ({ user }: Props) => {
...
}


package.json versions
"@clerk/nextjs": "^4.30.1"
"@clerk/types": "^4.2.0"
I tried to update the packages but it didn't work

The User, Organization, and other resources are exported from the @clerk/nextjs/server in the core-2 (>= 5) version.
import type { User } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';

